# asp.net MVC3 custom helper not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created the following code to render a table from below array

```
var fruit = new string[] { "apple", "pear", "tomato" };

   public static MvcHtmlString CustomGrid(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String Id, IList Items, IDictionary<string, string> Attributes)
        {
        if (Items == null || Items.Count == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

        return BuildGrid(Items, Id, Attributes);

    }

    public static MvcHtmlString BuildGrid(IList Items, string Id, IDictionary<string, string> attributes)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BuildHeader(sb, Items[0].GetType());

        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            BuildTableRow(sb, item);
        }

        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("table");
        builder.MergeAttributes(attributes);
        builder.MergeAttribute("name", Id);
        builder.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
        var Tag = builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(Tag);
    }

    public static void BuildTableRow(StringBuilder sb, object obj)
    {
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        sb.AppendLine("\t<tr>");
        foreach (var property in objType.GetProperties())
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("\t\t<td>{0}</td>\n", property.GetValue(obj, null));
           // sb.AppendFormat("\t\t<td>{0}</td>\n", obj);
        }
        sb.AppendLine("\t</tr>");
    }

    public static void BuildHeader(StringBuilder row, Type p)
    {
        row.AppendLine("\t<tr>");

        foreach (var property in p.GetProperties())
        {
            row.AppendFormat("\t\t<th>{0}</th>\n", p.Name);
        }
        row.AppendLine("\t</tr>");
    }
```

but it doesn't render any thing. I am using it like this:

```
Html.CustomGrid("myTable", (System.Collections.IList)fruit, null);
```

Please suggest solution to it.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code while debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put in some debugging statements to make sure *anything* is coming from the output. If its not, you are likely not using is like @Html.CustomGrid and instead using it in a code block where the output is not rendered to the response stream.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the @ from 
    Html.CustomGrid("myTable", (System.Collections.IList)fruit, null);